# Add Labeltext on Mkannotation image

Tags: objective-c, mkannotationview

I am using a MKMapView with custom placeMark, it has a NSString value and i'll like to add it as label to the mkannotationview image.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)MapView viewForAnnotation:(MyPlaceMark *)annotation{

static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

MKAnnotationView* MyView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];

MyView.canShowCallout=YES;
MyView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
return MyView;}
```

Which would be the best way to get it, I tried to add a label to the image but I had problems with the CGRect and I get nothing, any idea how to make it

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation view draws the image? In that case I would add a UILabel as a subview.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[yourView addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

Comment: Yes the annotation draws the image, I had problems finding the x, y for the initWithFrame, the width and the heigh i have it for image.size properties.

Comment: That was great i defined a context and it worked great! thanks!!

Comment: I have a class called CustomPin which adopts MKAnnotation. I want to put a number inside of the annotation itself. I've added a UILabel to the class and was planning on approaching it that way. Is that the right way?